# Есть ли где-нибудь полная классификация видов литературных произведений и их жанров?

Tags: литература, стилистика

Как их следует сортировать?

Что-то типа такого нужно:

1. Проза

1.1. Роман
1.2. Повесть
1.3. Рассказ
...
1.n. Очерк

2 Поэзия

2.1. Стихотворение
...
2.2. Поэма

и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже если исходить из определений видов литературных произведений, возникнут противоречия и условности. Например, сложности вызовет понятие "поэма", т.к. по желанию автора, это слово может применяться не только к стихотворному произведению, но и к прозе, написанной поэтическим языком. Аналогичные проблемы возникнут с градацией прозаических произведений на роман, повесть и рассказ, так как не существует чётко установленных объёмов для того, чтобы разграничить предел, где крупный рассказ переходит в повесть, и где крупная повесть становиться романом. Всё очень зыбко, непостоянно и условно в художественной литературе. Опять-таки, "Война и мир" — это роман или тетралогия? А что такое миниатюра? Стихотворение или короткий рассказ? И как отличить обычные рассказы и стихотворения от миниатюры? В зависимости от того, как вы определяете для себя эти понятия, будут распределяться и упорядочиваться виды произведений. С классификацией жанров тоже всё не однозначно, так как есть огромный пласт многожанровых произведений, к примеру, роман "Мастер и Маргарита".

Из всех рассуждений, предлагаю такой вывод: лучшей классификаций для вас будет собственная, сделанная на основе определений жанров и видов, отвечающая вашим собственным индивидуальным представлениям, при этом, не противоречащим общепринятым значениям этих понятий.

Answer (score 0):

Вам что именно нужно? Порядок следования литературных жанров или как их различать?

Answer (score 0):

"Лирики" так не работают.
Как насчёт поэзии не знаю, но классификация прозы намного сложнее. И сортировке по какому-либо внятному параметру не подлежит. Повесть может быть куда длиннее романа, а рассказ - короче очерка. "Деление" определяется по особенностям сюжета.

Answer (score 0):

Полная в учебнике для филфака, и то классификации в разных учебниках  будут различаться. Вот здесь посмотрите:http://veronasunrise.livejournal.com/33482.html

http://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?mode=lsntheme&themeid=26